# How do you display dynamic data using full outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A and B with a common ID field. I would like to do a full outer join on these tables, selecting the ID and either 'table A' or 'table B', depending on which table the ID came from.

```
SELECT ID, ['tableA'|'tableB']
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.ID IS NULL OR B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Simple matter of programming.   Please google and learn about the CASE expression in tSQL.

Comment: Like this? SELECT CASE WHEN ID IN (SELECT ID FROM A) THEN 'tableA' WHEN (SELECT ID FROM B)

Comment: I was thinking more like `WHEN B.ID IS NULL THEN 'TableA'...` but there are multiple ways `CASE` can be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(A.ID , B.ID) AS ID , 
       CASE  WHEN A.ID IS NOT NULL AND B.ID IS NULL THEN  <tableA results> 
             WHEN A.ID IS NULL AND B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN  <tableB results>  
       END AS results
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.ID IS NULL OR B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: @TT. Agreed. But looking at the where clause it appears that we only pull data if A.ID IS NULL OR B.ID IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with after a little help from Tab.

```
SELECT ID, SELECT CASE WHEN ID IN (SELECT ID FROM A) THEN 'tableA' 
                       WHEN ID IN (SELECT ID FROM B) THEN 'tableB'
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.ID IS NULL OR B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: having nested select statements is very inefficient as they function like nested loops.

Comment: Thanks for the info Kamran. I'll try your solution.

Comment: just replace <tableA results>, and <tableB results> with the column or text that you want to retrieve.